# Android - displaying text in center of progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have already made a horizontal progress bar and it works perfectly. I would like to display a textview or something similar right in the middle of it showing a countdown as the bar is loading. Keep in mind its not a progress dialog, progress bar resides inside an activity and shows a countdown timer. Can anyone help me out, whats the best way to do this and how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 48):

If your `ProgressBar` and `TextView` are inside a `RelativeLayout` you can give the `ProgressBar` an id, and then align the `TextView` with the `ProgressBar` using that. It should then show on top of the `ProgressBar`. Make sure the background is transparent so that you can still see the `ProgressBar`

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/PROGRESS_BAR"/>

    <!-- TextView with transparent background -->
    <TextView
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/PROGRESS_BAR"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/PROGRESS_BAR"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/PROGRESS_BAR"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/PROGRESS_BAR"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Only this  android:layout_alignTop="@id/simpleProgressBar" work fine for me.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Need closing tags on the textView and ProgressBar elements

Comment: Becomes problematic if font scaling is introduced by the user. The progressbar bounds don't wrap around the expanding text.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a FrameLayout to display the TextView over the ProgressBar:

```
...
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Good solution.  Not sure of the purpose of the Relative Layout -- seems superfluous.

Comment: @dazed FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.
Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

In resume, RelativeLayout is better when you want to put many views and organize them relatively to each other.

Answer (score 6):

You can set  **LinearLayout** with **RelativeLayout** inside it and make
RelativeLayout **Height** & **width** equal to **wrap_content** then in the TextView under the ProgressBar you will add android:**layout_centerInParent="true"**

Example :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="65" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="6:00 AM"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

that is what worked for me:

```
             <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                  <ProgressBar
                      android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                      style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                      android:progressDrawable="@drawable/customprogressbar"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:max="100"/>

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/progressBarinsideText"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                      android:gravity="center"
                    />
              </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I am using the Frame Layout and put text inside the Frame Layout

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/programStatusTextView"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/programStatusTextView"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/programStatusTextView">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/battery">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/batteryIndicaterBar"
                style="@style/CustomProgressBarHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="119dp"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:max="100"
                android:minHeight="10dip"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:progress="0"
                android:progressBackgroundTintMode="src_over"
                android:progressTint="@color/green"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Here is the output I am getting

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to achieve this but nothing worked. Thanks for including the output image as well!

Comment: How does the `@style/CustomProgressBarHorizontal` look like?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to display progress text above a spinner centered on a web view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/help_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#F22"
        android:scrollbars="none" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progressBarMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading, please wait..."
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/progressBar"
        android:background="#00000000" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the ProgressBar and the TextView inside a Relative Layout and add the following line to both of these children's XML file:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

This should force both the ProgressBar and the TextView to be displayed in the Center of the same Relative layout.

**This can also work if you want to display a Textfield inside a Circular ProgressBar.**

PS. if you further want to show the textview above or below (vertically) the progress bar, then you can adjust the 'margin' element of the TextView.

Answer (score -5):

[Source tutorial](https://www.freakyjolly.com/show-progress-bar-with-text-and-title-in-android/)

[image]

In Activity we can Show and Dismiss **ProgressBar** using the following methods

```
// Method to show Progress bar
private void showProgressDialogWithTitle(String substring) {
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    //Without this user can hide loader by tapping outside screen
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage(substring);
    progressDialog.show();
}

// Method to hide/ dismiss Progress bar
private void hideProgressDialogWithTitle() {
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Check other

Comment: Your link provides a how-to on `ProgressDialog` which is deprecated. The question is asking about a `ProgressBar`, which is a totally different thing.

Comment: Question is related to progressbar not progress dialog