# How to display progress bar in Bootstrap type in my app?

Tags: android

I've been trying to search on Google ways to implement percents (%) user interface and couldn't find anything that may help!
My goal is to make progress like the **Bootstrap Progress bar** ([see here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress))
in Android.

My goal is to show player win percentage (like 55%) in a modern way.

I've been checking the ProgressBar and ProgressDialog but they are just progress circles for data and has nothing to do with what I need.

The closest thing I faced is the SeekBar, but SeekBar meant to be changed, and I need only an indicator for **showing percentage** without changing it.

Of course I can make a label and write "55%" but I'm pretty sure there is something modern out there.. Any idea for it?

Thank you!

Comment: These might me helpful:                                                    http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/android-s-progress-bars.html                                                                                                        ProgressBar with percentage:                                          http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-create-custom-progress-bar-and.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been checking the ProgressBar and ProgressDialog but they are just progress circles for data and has nothing to do with what I need.

`ProgressBar` has multiple styles. While the default style is a circle, you are welcome to style it as a bar, using `style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`, as is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html), or via `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"` as is shown in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Progress/BarSampler).

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to label inside the ProgressBar? like writing number of precentage or descriptive label?

Comment: @AndroidWonderer: `ProgressBar` does not have support for that directly. You can try layering a `TextView` on top of it, or subclassing `ProgressBar` and rendering your own text, or look for a third-party progress indicator library that has features that you like.

Answer (score 1):

A `ProgressBar` is indeed the widget you're looking for. If the default style is a circle, displaying an indeterminate progress, you can switch to a linear one:

```
<ProgressBar
     style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />
```

Then you can define a max value (`android:max`) and a specific percent with `setProgress(int progress)`.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to label inside the ProgressBar? like writing number of precentage or descriptive label?

Comment: You will have to use a separate `TextView`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18411668/775894

Answer (score 1):

Here is your **Bootstrap for Android**:

https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap

Comment: So beautiful! Cool! Thanks!