# ProgressDialog is deprecated.What is the alternate one to use?

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I have come across to see that `ProgressDialog` is now deprecated. What would be alternate one to use in place of that apart from `ProgressBar`. 
I am using android studio version 2.3.3.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.show();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ProgressDialog is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351127/progressdialog-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 231):

Yes, in `API level 26` it's deprecated. Instead, you can use `progressBar`.

**To create it programmatically:**

First get a reference to the root layout

```
RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.display);  //specify here Root layout Id
```

or

```
RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(this);
```

Then add the progress bar

```
progressBar = new ProgressBar(youractivity.this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
layout.addView(progressBar, params);
```

To show the progress bar

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

To hide the progress bar

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

To disable the user interaction you just need to add the following
code

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

To get user interaction back you just need to add the following code

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Just for future reference, change the `android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall` to `android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal`.

The code below only works above `API level 21`

```
progressBar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
```

---

**To create it via xml:**

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/framelauout"
        android:indeterminateTint="#1a09d6"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"/>
```

In your activity

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
```

Showing/hiding the progress bar is the same

```
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // To show the ProgressBar 
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // To hide the ProgressBar
```

Here is a sample image of what it would look like:

[image]

Comment: It's like you been using this and you go like yeah finally progress dialog is deprecated, so I can show my potential to the world :D, just kidding, thanks so much for that detailed answer.

Comment: but how to setMessage() to it?

Comment: look at this ;  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410984/android-displaying-text-in-center-of-progress-bar

Comment: please update the xml code to "@android:color/white"

Comment: To get horizontal Bar please use:                                                        **ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(youractivity.this,null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);     
 progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);**

Comment: Wow, this is actually not a good approach as of today, you shouln't block the UI, that's why this got deprecated! Oussema Aroua solution is better.

Comment: @David Thing is, blocking the UI is exactly what I want to do, because I don't want the user to be able to interact with in until the background task is finished.

Comment: @Ben Jaguar Marshall that's a REALLY bad app behavior and the last thing you should do, it's what all Google Devs and the documentation say.

Comment: @David How is that bad app behaviour? The user should not be able to do anything before the app is ready; otherwise you'll get issues. Showing a "please wait" type dialog has been a pretty standard way of doing it for decades.

Comment: @Ben Jaguar Marshall that's straight false, please read more and watch more Google videos, since at least 2014 they strongly discourage doing so! NEVER EVER block the UI, you must learn how to run operations in the background and react accordingly once they finished.

Comment: @David So you're saying that Google advocates that users should be able to open empty dropdowns, see placeholder items and press buttons while the background thread is preparing the app's data? That's horrible design! A "please wait" dialog should be shown, preferably animated to show the app hasn't stalled, and then allow the user to interact with the UI once the app is prepared. If however you mean "don't do heavy stuff on the UI thread", then that makes sense. When I say "blocking the UI", I mean preventing interaction by the user, not doing work on the UI thread.

Comment: So, now instead one line of code I need white dozens with about the same result? Great work google!

Comment: There are problems with this solution "as is", particularly if you are using fragment navigation (single fragment apps). This does not disable backwards nav, so clicking said nav will result in the the previous screen being untouchable (and likely interrupting you async). It also will not survive a config change (say device re-orientation) regardless of whether you are using fragments or not.

Answer (score 62):

you can use `AlertDialog` as `ProgressDialog` refer below code for the `ProgressDialog`. This function you need to call whenever you show a progress dialog.

**Code:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;

public class ProgressHelper {

    private static AlertDialog dialog = null;

    public static void showDialog(Context context, String message) {
        if(dialog == null){
            int llPadding = 30;
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            ll.setPadding(llPadding, llPadding, llPadding, llPadding);
            ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            llParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            ll.setLayoutParams(llParam);

            ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressBar.setPadding(0, 0, llPadding, 0);
            progressBar.setLayoutParams(llParam);

            llParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            llParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            TextView tvText = new TextView(context);
            tvText.setText(message);
            tvText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            tvText.setTextSize(20);
            tvText.setLayoutParams(llParam);

            ll.addView(progressBar);
            ll.addView(tvText);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setView(ll);

            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            if (window != null) {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                layoutParams.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
                layoutParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                layoutParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
            }
        }
    }

    public static  boolean isDialogVisible(){
        if(dialog != null){
            return dialog.isShowing();
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static  void dismissDialog(){
        if(dialog != null){
            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: How to dismiss it?

Comment: make one base class like BaseActivity then after adding this piece of code, also add one method dismiss dialog but for that, you need to define 'AlertDialog dialog' object globally

Comment: then simply call dialog.dismiss() method inside your hide dialog method.

Comment: Everything is fine but on tapping anywhere on screen dialog getting dismissed.Service calls in progress and suer is able to dismiss it and play with the ui which is not good right.Any Solution ?

Comment: You can set it not cancellable, but rotating the device or use split screen it would be dismissed anyway and the user can interact with the UI which is not ready. Maybe `AlertDialog` should not be used here.

Comment: Best way to show "Loading" dialog without additional XML layout, thanks!

Comment: I am unable to dismiss it. I am calling it at `onClick` of a button.

Comment: @FaisalQayyum makes AlertDialog dialog instance global and used for dismissing.

Comment: @KishanDonga `AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog();` it is giving me `cannot reslove constructor AlterDialog()`

Answer (score 39):

You can simply design an xml interface for your progressbar and pass it as a view to a AlertDialog, then show or dismiss the dialog anytime you want.

**progress.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="13dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loader"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/loading_msg"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/loader"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code code that displays the progress dialog. Just copy this code and paste it your fragment.

```
Dialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(R.layout.progress);
        // This should be called once in your Fragment's onViewCreated() or in Activity onCreate() method to avoid dialog duplicates.
        dialog = builder.create();
    }
    
//   This method is used to control the progress dialog.
      private void setDialog(boolean show){
               if (show)dialog.show();
                    else dialog.dismiss();
           }
```

Then just call the method whenever you want to show the progressdialog and pass true as an argument to show it or false to dismiss the dialog.

Comment: @Alok Rajasukumaran it seems you're using activity, simply replace it with `this` , so that it look like this `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);` .Please make sure you're copying the right code.

Comment: `layout_toEndOf` can be removed since not for `LinearLayout`

Comment: I have been trying to show progress bar via alter dialog but i am having some issues can you please check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63393532/8868582)?

Comment: when I call setDialog(false), the dialog won't disappear. Only if I touch the screen it wii be gone

Comment: I know it's way too late to help @Darksymphony, but setDialog should not be calling builder.create(). That should only happen once, or a second dialog will be created when the calling code wants to dismiss() the first. Thus, the first one is still shown...

Comment: @CarlSmith You're right. I provided the code snippet as an example of how the progress dialog can be achieved.

Answer (score 33):

Yes, ProgressDialog is deprecated but Dialog isn't.

You can inflate your own XML file ( containing a progress bar and a loading text) into your dialog object and then display or hide it using the `show()` and `dismiss()` functions.
Here is an example (Kotlin):

**ProgressDialog class**:

```
class ProgressDialog {
companion object {
    fun progressDialog(context: Context): Dialog{
        val dialog = Dialog(context)
        val inflate = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog, null)
        dialog.setContentView(inflate)
        dialog.setCancelable(false)
        dialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(
                ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        return dialog
    }
  }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:padding="13dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar"
    android:text="Loading..." />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**In your code**:
Just do `var dialog = ProgressDialog.progressDialog(context)`

To show: `dialog.show()`

To hide: `dialog.dismiss()`

Comment: Great solution! Just posted an alternative version of the ProgressDialog class below.

Answer (score 32):

ProgressBar is very simple and easy to use,
i am intending to make this same as simple progress dialog.
first step is that you can make xml layout of the dialog that you want to show, let say we name this layout

> layout_loading_dialog.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Please wait! This may take a moment." />
</LinearLayout>
```

next step is create AlertDialog which will show this layout with ProgressBar

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setCancelable(false); // if you want user to wait for some process to finish,
builder.setView(R.layout.layout_loading_dialog);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

now all that is left is to show and hide this dialog in our click events
like this

```
dialog.show(); // to show this dialog
dialog.dismiss(); // to hide this dialog
```

and thats it, it should work, as you can see it is farely simple and easy to implement ProgressBar instead of ProgressDialog.
now you can show/dismiss this dialog box in either Handler or ASyncTask, its up to your need

Comment: Please, change `progress_dialog.show();` to `builder.show();`. Thank you.

Comment: I have changed the name to right AlertDialog object on, `show()` / `dismiss()`, but I didn't put `builder.show()` because then to dismiss it we would have to do `dialog.dismiss()` which is kind of confusing for someone who likes to keep their code simple and easy to understand, and also because `builder.show()` returns  `AlertDialog` object, and we will have to save that reference like `AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();` then do `dialog.dismiss()`,
its easier to have `builder.create()` return in some `AlertDialog` object, and then use that object to show and hide the dialog

Comment: We may use "runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {    @Override     public void run() {     dialog.show/dismiss();    }     });", if the calling thread is not Main UI Thread. ( useful when we use to call from WebView - shouldoverride methods. )

Comment: I have been trying to show progress bar via alter dialog but i am having some issues can you please check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63393532/8868582)?

Answer (score 31):

> This class was deprecated in API level 26. ProgressDialog is a modal
>   dialog, which prevents the user from interacting with the app. Instead
>   of using this class, you should use a progress indicator like
>   ProgressBar, which can be embedded in your app's UI. Alternatively,
>   you can use a notification to inform the user of the task's progress. [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

It's deprecated at `Android O` because of `Google` new UI standard

Comment: "This class was deprecated in API level 26" is used instead of a date. They don't want you to use it anymore. Yes, it is because of new UI standards, but they apply for every API level...

Comment: "It's deprecated at Android O because of Google new UI standard" - link please new UI standard

Comment: And the reason for deprecating it is because it blocks user input? Sometimes I wonder what kind of powder Google engineers are snorting. It's much easier to use a blocking dialog than having to hide/disable input controls and then enable a progressbar. Foolish thinking on Google's part.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 The Android UI is designed around making the user feel a false sense of freedom at the cost of expensive workarounds to prevent fatal errors that result from it. Wait until you get into permissions and what the carriers have paid Google to say you can and can't access.

Comment: I guess they're more interested in preventing abuse of modal dialogs: sometimes they are shown to make the user wait for the end of an operation in circumstances in which the user shouldn't need to wait at all, but could continue doing other things, so making them wait unnecessarily degrades the user experience. Notwithstanding, there are plenty of circumstances in which there's no choice for the user but wait for an operation to complete, so I agree that there should be a non-deprecated standard method for these cases instead of forcing each developer implementing their own.

Comment: I have been trying to show progress bar via alter dialog but i am having some issues can you please check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63393532/8868582)?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 I hope after 2 years you learned more, "It's much easier to use a blocking dialog" who cares what's easier for the developer, the user is the king and the app should behave in the best way FOR THE USER.

Comment: @David Look at the upvotes on my comment. Tell those people too. I think the decision by Google was more political. And I'm still using dialog boxes. So, jokes on you and Google.

Comment: The hubris of the Android team unilaterally deciding they know what my customers need better than I do is simply incredible.  Blocking interaction with the UI is a very common need and used to be served perfectly by `ProgressDialog`.  Now I have to waste yet another chunk of my life reinventing the wheel AGAIN.

Answer (score 17):

You don't need to import any custom library.

I prefer to use the modern `AlertDialog` so this is the **Kotlin** version for the great answer posted by [Kishan Donga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49272722/1894067) in this page.

### Kotlin code:

```
fun setProgressDialog(context:Context, message:String):AlertDialog {
    val llPadding = 30
    val ll = LinearLayout(context)
    ll.orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
    ll.setPadding(llPadding, llPadding, llPadding, llPadding)
    ll.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    var llParam = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    llParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    ll.layoutParams = llParam

    val progressBar = ProgressBar(context)
    progressBar.isIndeterminate = true
    progressBar.setPadding(0, 0, llPadding, 0)
    progressBar.layoutParams = llParam

    llParam = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    llParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    val tvText = TextView(context)
    tvText.text = message
    tvText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
    tvText.textSize = 20.toFloat()
    tvText.layoutParams = llParam

    ll.addView(progressBar)
    ll.addView(tvText)

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    builder.setCancelable(true)
    builder.setView(ll)

    val dialog = builder.create()
    val window = dialog.window
    if (window != null) {
        val layoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams()
        layoutParams.copyFrom(dialog.window?.attributes)
        layoutParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        layoutParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                dialog.window?.attributes = layoutParams
    }
    return dialog
}
```

### Usage:

```
val dialog = setProgressDialog(this, "Loading..")
dialog.show()
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: how to use in fragment? what is context in fragment?

Comment: Usually in your fragment you can get your current view, so the context should be: `view!!.context`

Answer (score 13):

Well if you really wants to go against their will, still you can use [Sweet Alert Dialog](https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog) or create one on your own.

```
progress_dialog_layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Downloading data. Please wait.." />
    </TableRow>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java code:**

```
AlertDialog b;
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;

public void ShowProgressDialog() {
dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DataDownloadActivity.this);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog_layout, null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
            dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            b = dialogBuilder.create();
            b.show();
        }

        public void HideProgressDialog(){

            b.dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: I have had terrible experiences with SweetAlertDialog in a production setting, be very cautious as it leaks from window to window.

Comment: for me `HideProgress` does nothing.

Comment: Why to use a library just to show a progress dialog?

Comment: a note, here `TableRow` it's the same as using a horizontal `LinearLayout`  given that the parent is not a `TableLayout`  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow

Answer (score 7):

ProgressBar is best alternative for ProgressDialog. 
A user interface element that indicates the progress of an operation.

For more info see this **Google doc:** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: He said "apart from progressbar".

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned on the [documentation page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) the alternative **is** `ProgressBar`. `ProgressDialog`'s look can be replicated by placing a `ProgressBar` into an `AlertDialog`.

You can still use it, but Android does not want you to use it, that is why it is deprecated. So you should consider solving your problem in another way, like embedding a `ProgressBar` into your `Layout`.

Comment: @PeterHaddad It works "normally" in api 28 in my project and the same as in lower apis. As the deprecation suggests, it is no longer supported and may not work in the future.

Answer (score 4):

> [**`ProgressDialog`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) was deprecated in API level 26 .

<s>**`"Deprecated"`**</s> refers to functions or elements that are in the process of being replaced by newer ones.

> ProgressDialog is a modal dialog, which prevents the user from interacting with
>   the app. Instead of using this class, you should use a progress
>   indicator like [**`ProgressBar`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html), which can be embedded in your app's
>   UI.

Advantage

I would personally say that **`ProgressBar`** has the edge over the two .**`ProgressBar`** is a user interface element that indicates the progress of an operation. Display progress bars to a user in a **non-interruptive** way. Show the progress bar in your app's user interface.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this [guide](https://material.io/guidelines/components/progress-activity.html) could help you.

Usually I prefer to make custom AlertDialogs with indicators. It solves such problems like customization of the App view.

Answer (score 2):

It may help to other people.

Lots of popular apps have the different approach to show the progress of anything like network request, file loading etc. Loading spinner doesn't show the how much content has been loaded or remaining to load. There is a period of uncertainty which is bad in the perspective of UI/UX. Lot of popular apps(Facebook, Linkedin etc) has resolved this issue by showing the bare bones UI displays first. Then the loaded content is gradually populated on-screen.

I have used the [shimmer](https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android)  for my apps to solve this issue.

There is a good [article](http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/stop-using-loading-spinner-theres-something-better/) about this which will be beneficial for other people

Answer (score 2):

I use DelayedProgressDialog from https://github.com/Q115/DelayedProgressDialog It does the same as ProgressDialog with the added benefit of a delay if necessary.

Using it is similar to ProgressDialog before Android O:

```
DelayedProgressDialog progressDialog = new DelayedProgressDialog();
progressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can use this [class](https://github.com/Livin21/MissMe/blob/master/ProgressDialog.kt) I wrote. It offers only the basic
>   functions. If you want a fully functional ProgressDialog, then use
>   this lightweight [library](https://github.com/Livin21/MissMe).

### Gradle Setup

Add the following dependency to module/build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.lmntrx.android.library.livin.missme:missme:0.1.5'
```

### How to use it?

Usage is similar to original ProgressDialog

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new 
progressDialog(YourActivity.this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.show();
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

**NB**: You must override activity's `onBackPressed()`

Java8 Implementation:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    progressDialog.onBackPressed(
            () -> {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return null;
            }
    );
}
```

Kotlin Implementation:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
   progressDialog.onBackPressed { super.onBackPressed() }
}
```

- Refer [Sample App](https://github.com/Livin21/MissMe/tree/master/MissMe) for the full implementation
- Full documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/Livin21/MissMe/blob/master/Documentation/index.md)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my kotlin version of the ProgressDialog class suggested by @Han

```
class ProgressDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context) {
init {
    val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.progress_dialog, null)
    setContentView(view)
    setCancelable(false)
    window?.setBackgroundDrawable(
        ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

**Another solution with Kotlin and androidx DialogFragment**

By using DialogFragment you don't have to resize the window every time and on every screen where you need to show the dialog, I think this is a cleaner solution

1. Create dialog class

```
class BaseProgressDialog : DialogFragment() {

    companion object {
        const val DIALOG_TAG = "BaseProgressDialogFragment"
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it, R.style.MainAlertDialog)
            val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater
            val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog, null)

            builder.setView(dialogView)
            builder.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        dialog?.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        dialog?.setCancelable(false)
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val size = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size_80dp)
        dialog?.window?.setLayout(size, size)
    }
}
```

2. Create style in your `styles.xml`

```xml
<style name="MainAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_alert_dialog</item>
</style>
```

3. Create background for your dialog `bg_alert_dialog.xml`

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorSecondary"/>
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/radius_10dp" />
</shape>
```

4. Create layout for dialog `progress_dialog.xml`

```xml
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_alert_dialog"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_16dp">

    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_40dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_40dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        app:indicatorColor="?attr/colorPrimary" />

</LinearLayout>
```

5. Call dialog in the Fragment

```kotlin
private var progressDialog = BaseProgressDialog()
activity?.let {
   progressDialog.show(it.supportFragmentManager, BaseProgressDialog.DIALOG_TAG)
}
```

And this is what it will look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple trick

//initialize

```
val dialog : Dialog = Dialog(this)
```

//set layout

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.view_loading)
```

//show dialog

```
dialog.show()
```

// remove white background

```
dialog.window.setbackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the progress dialog, user cannot do any kind of work. All the background processes are stopped during progress dialog. So, It is advisable to user progress-bar instead of progress dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Here my version for an indeterminate progress dialog:

layout_loading_dialog.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:id="@+id/message"
        tools:text="Please wait..." />
</LinearLayout>
```

IndeterminateProgressDialog.kt:

```
class IndeterminateProgressDialog(context: Context) : AlertDialog(context) {
    private val messageTextView: TextView

    init {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_loading_dialog, null)
        messageTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.message)
        setView(view)
    }

    override fun setMessage(message: CharSequence?) {
        this.messageTextView.text = message.toString()
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
   val dialog = IndeterminateProgressDialog(context)
                    dialog.setMessage("Please wait...")
                    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
                    dialog.setCancelable(false)
                    dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

create a xml file with progress-bar and other view and inflate your derived Dialog class view with this xml file or Alertdialog derived class. Which have been provided in other solution with detailed.
But if you want a go to solution or existed lib. i found these two.

1. https://github.com/Livin21/MissMe
2. https://github.com/skydoves/ProgressView

These are just perfect and two the point as per need.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **SpotDialog** by using the library wasabeef you can find the complete tutorial from the following link:

> [SpotsDialog Example in Android](https://www.droidblogger.com/progress-dialog-deprecated-alternative-is-spotsdialog/)