# xamarin code error after update (is Obsolete: deprecated)

Tags: android, xamarin

I am developing an app in xamarin 2017, My latest platform version was 7.1, but now I update my visual studio, also I update the sdk to latest version, now when I compile or build my app I get many error in my code saying for example (Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning CS0618  'ProgressDialog' is obsolete: 'This class is obsoleted in this android platform'    MyMap   D:\xamarine\rekshaDrivers\MyMap\MainActivity.cs 142 Active
and there are many error like this (is obsolete:deprecated) and cant build my app

the current target platform is v8.0 and the previous was 7.1
any idea to fix those erros. thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373007/progressdialog-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternate-one-to-use