# Avoiding boilerplate with ProgressDialog and AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have an app with many activities, and lots of them hit various json web APIs to load & show data.  A common pattern is similar to:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show( ... );

        // This is a custom API which wraps AsynkTask and calls my callback in onPostExecute
        DoWebThing(url, new Callback() {
            public void onSuccess(String json) {
                pd.dismiss();
                // Do other UI stuff with the json data
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This works great, and is similar to a lot of code snippets you'll find on SO and tutorials.  The problem is that the user can leave the page while the background process is running.  In this case, I get a logcat error about leaking the view (the ProgressDialog), and then I'll crash when I dismiss it or do my other UI stuff.

I've tried adding an early check in onSuccess:

```
if (!pd.isShowing()) {
    return;
}
```

This fixes the crash on some devices, but not others, and we still get the logcat error about a leaked view.

I've tried replacing the `pd.isShowing()` check with `MyActivity.this.isFinishing()`, which doesn't help with anything (on the device I'm currently testing with).  Still get the logcat error and crash.

I've tried `MyActivity.this.isDestroyed()`, which fixes the crash, but only works on SDK 17+ and still get the logcat error.

The only option to truly fix this is to make my progress dialog a member variable and override `OnDestroy()`:

```
ProgressDialog mPd;
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mProgressDialog != null) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        mProgressDialog = null;
    }
}
```

Now in my callback I can check if `mProgressDialog == null`.

This works great.  No crash and no logcat error about leaking a view.  But it feels like a lot of boilerplate - I have to make the progress dialog a member variable and override `OnDestroy()` in all of my (many) activities that do background stuff.

I'm not seeing a better option, but wanted a second opinion before I start updating lots of activities.

Comment: **FYI** [`ProgressDialog is deprecated`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373007/progressdialog-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternate-one-to-use)

Comment: Better to proceed with Live Data and Architectural components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one Activity, say NetworkBaseActivity. Create the ProgressDialog and handle onDestroy in this activity. Also create a method called `showMyDialog()` and `hideMyDialog()` to show and hide the dialog(from subclasses). Now all your activities that do background stuff only need to extend this activity. To show the dialog call `showMyDialog()` and to hide it call `hideMyDialog()`

Something like this:

```
public class NetworkBaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ProgressDialog myDialog;
    onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        // initialize myDialog
    }

    public void showDialog(){
       // show myDialog if not shown
    }
    public void hideDialog(){
      // hide myDialog if already shown
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        mProgressDialog = null;
    }
}

public class YourActivity extends NetworkBaseActivity{

}
```

I typed the code right into stackoverflow so pardon my typos, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid changing the base class for all of my activities, but I agree this seems like the best option.