# Alternate of ProgressDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

In API level 26, ProgressDialog is deprecated. In my app I want to show the progress of my downloading task with title and cancel option. What would be the alternate option to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46639138/5684956  It may helpful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not adding a **ProgressView** to your Dialog view without creating a custom layout for Dialog

```
  LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams progressParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        progressParam.setMargins(0, 40, 0, 40);// set margin to progressBar
        progressBar.setLayoutParams(progressParam);
        linearLayout.addView(progressBar);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Loading ")
                .setMessage("Please waite until the map loaded")
                .setView(linearLayout).setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();     
                    }
                });
                
        builder.create().show();
```