# Progress Dialog getting dismissed before displaying fetched data from firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, progressdialog

I am fetching data from document and then displaying it on an activity, but it takes some time to display it so i wanted to put a dialog while the job is geting done.
so i added progressdialog (i know it's deprecated, i'll use custom dialog afterwards), but the problem is dialog is getting called and is getting dismissed instantly even before data get displayed. i don't know how to listen if data is got displayed successfully so  i can put dismiss method after that.
here's code :

```
package com.example.firestooredemo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class StudentProfileData extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    String S_ID,id;
    TextView Student,MArks,Time;
//    Timestamp t= new Timestamp("160536400","13000000000");
    Map<String, Object> Stud;
    String TAG = "Datacheck";
    Sdm Stud_Data=new Sdm();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_profile_data);

        ProgressDialog Pd=new ProgressDialog(this);
        Pd.setCancelable(false);
        Pd.setMessage("Loading Student Data ...");
        Pd.show();


        Student = findViewById(R.id.Stud_Name);
        Time = findViewById(R.id.Timestamp1);
        MArks = findViewById(R.id.MarksView);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        S_ID = intent.getStringExtra("S_ID");
        id=intent.getStringExtra("Path");
        DocumentReference Stud_Doc= db.collection("EM_DEMO2").document("10th_STD").collection(S_ID).document(id);
        Stud_Doc.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                Stud = documentSnapshot.getData();
                Stud_Data.readData(Stud);

                Log.d(TAG,id+documentSnapshot.getData().toString());
                Student.setText(Stud_Data.getStudentname());
                Time.setText(Stud_Data.getDateTime());
                MArks.setText(Stud_Data.getMarks());

            }
        });
        Log.d(TAG,"YAAAY");

        if(Pd.isShowing()){
              Pd.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

the output looks like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl7JH.jpg

that delay of 0.5 sec or something is the problem.
please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Progress Dialog` dismissed instantly because you set `Pd.dismiss()` directly inside `onCreate` method.

Set `Pd.dismiss()` inside `onSuccess` so the `Progress Dialog` will be dismissed after finish fetching data from Firebase.

`Progress Dialog` is deprecated. You can use `Progress Bar` as its alternative. It's easy to use, all you have to do are:

1. define `Progress Bar` element in xml file
2. set visibility to `GONE` or `VISIBLE` for the `Progress Bar` element in java file.

Here are some references for `Progress Bar`:

1. Official documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar
2. Example: https://abhiandroid.com/ui/progressbar
3. Another use in stackoverflow: [ProgressDialog is deprecated.What is the alternate one to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373007/progressdialog-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternate-one-to-use)