# Alertdialog running ongoing dosen't dismiss or cancel

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-progressbar, android-dialog

According this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49272722/4205927) , I wanna to show dilaog until the next 10 posts is loaded so I created the static alertDialog method to use it in different places in my app, but the problem is the dialog doesn't cancel or dismiss

[image]

**setProgressDialog** in Utils class

```
 public static AlertDialog setProgressDialog(Context context) {

        int llPadding = 30;
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        ll.setPadding(llPadding, llPadding, llPadding, llPadding);
        ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        llParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        ll.setLayoutParams(llParam);

        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressBar.setPadding(0, 0, llPadding, 0);
        progressBar.setLayoutParams(llParam);

        llParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        llParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        TextView tvText = new TextView(context);
        tvText.setText("Loading ...");
        tvText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        tvText.setTextSize(20);
        tvText.setLayoutParams(llParam);

        ll.addView(progressBar);
        ll.addView(tvText);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setView(ll);

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        if (window != null) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            layoutParams.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
            layoutParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            layoutParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
        }
        return dialog;
    }
```

then I used it in HomeFragment on click load more button

```
binding.loadMoreBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            Utils.setProgressDialog(requireContext());

            if (Utils.hasNetworkAccess(requireContext())) {
                postViewModel.getPosts();
//                Log.w(TAG, "loadMoreBtn: "+dialog.isShowing() );
            } else {
                postViewModel.getAllItemsFromDataBase.getValue();
            }
            Utils.setProgressDialog(requireContext()).cancel();
            Utils.setProgressDialog(requireContext()).dismiss();

        });
```

**PS:** I tried also to create dialog `AlertDialog dialog = Utils.setProgressDialog(requireContext());` instead to call the method directly then `dialod.show()`, and after the `getPosts` cancel or dismiss it but it dosen't appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a flag boolean in the viewmodel to detect loading state

```
public final MutableLiveData<Boolean> isLoading = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

and use it in `getPosts()` like this

```
public void getPosts() {
        Log.e(TAG, finalURL.getValue());

        isLoading.setValue(true);
        repository.remoteDataSource.getPostList(finalURL.getValue())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Response<PostList>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull Response<PostList> postListResponse) {

                        if (postListResponse.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (postListResponse.body() != null
                                    && postListResponse.body().getNextPageToken() != null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, postListResponse.body().getNextPageToken());
                                token.setValue(postListResponse.body().getNextPageToken());
                                isLoading.setValue(false);
                            }
                            postListMutableLiveData.setValue(postListResponse.body());
```

and finally in the fragment on button click

```
binding.loadMoreBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            AlertDialog dialog = Utils.setProgressDialog(requireContext());

            postViewModel.isLoading.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), isLoading -> {
                if (isLoading) {
                    dialog.show();
                } else {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            if (Utils.hasNetworkAccess(requireContext())) {
                postViewModel.getPosts();
                Log.w(TAG, "loadMoreBtn: " + dialog.isShowing());
            } else {
                postViewModel.isLoading.postValue(true);
                postViewModel.getAllItemsFromDataBase.getValue();
                postViewModel.isLoading.postValue(false);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> binding.loadMoreBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
>
>         Utils.setProgressDialog(requireContext());
>
>         if (Utils.hasNetworkAccess(requireContext())) {
>             postViewModel.getPosts(); //                Log.w(TAG, "loadMoreBtn: "+dialog.isShowing() );
>         } else {
>             postViewModel.getAllItemsFromDataBase.getValue();
>         }
>         Utils.setProgressDialog(requireContext()).cancel();
>         Utils.setProgressDialog(requireContext()).dismiss();
>
>     });
> ```

Here you invoked the static method `Utils.setProgressDialog()` multiple times; and each time it is called, it returns back a brand new dialog, so you'd dismiss a dialog that is not displayed on the screen.

Instead, you need to store the dialog that is returned from the first call to the method into a variable:

```
AlertDialog dialog = Utils.setProgressDialog(requireContext());
```

And then call `dismiss` on that dialog version: `dialog.dismiss()` or `dialog.cancel()` whenever you need to dismiss it.

Comment: I tried this `AlertDialog dialog = Utils.setProgressDialog(requireContext());` then
            `dialog.show();` and dismiss the dialog dosen't apper, it seems the dialog returns from the method is different than the one created

Comment: @DrMido As per the code you shared you dismiss the dialog just after you show it; so it does not take the chance to be displayed on the screen.. Instead you need to have a callback when the `postViewModel.getPosts` or when `postViewModel.getAllItemsFromDataBase.getValue()` are finished so that you can dismiss the dialog then. Let me know if something is confusing.

Comment: If I understand you well, I can't create callback from this method `postViewModel.getPosts();` becasue it's  void inside the viewmodel and contains a rxjava retrofit call, I think this well' make the problem too complecated to just show dialog with progressbar, at the first time I show the dialog with progressbar but it dosen't dismiss, at the second time when I use `AlertDialog dialog = Utils.setProgressDialog(requireContext());` it dosen't seen at all :"D, there's something missing

Comment: @DrMido If you just want to see it at the second option, just remove `dialog.dismiss()` and `dialog.cancel()` :)

Comment: thanks I got it, I'll search about how to detect if Response call finished to dismiss it

Comment: Cool.. I would suggest to search for the java listener interface callback. It is the simplest one.. Good luck!